# Merge [isolatedstorage] and [isolated-storage] tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I suggest that we merge [isolatedstorage](/questions/tagged/isolatedstorage) and [isolated-storage](/questions/tagged/isolated-storage). Currently there are more questions tagged with [isolatedstorage](/questions/tagged/isolatedstorage). Though, I don't know which tag should be the main/master tag.

Comment: I'm hoping a few people will weigh in on which direction this synonym should go. Neither tag has a wiki, so we're free in that regard. I'm leaning towards making [isolated-storage] the canonical tag, even though the non-hyphenated version currently has more usage.

Comment: No real association with the topic, but I think [isolated-storage] looks better.

Answer (score 2):

[isolatedstorage](/questions/tagged/isolatedstorage) probably exists because the namespace is called [`System.IO.IsolatedStorage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.aspx). The concept is referred to in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx), however, as "isolated storage" (not even a proper noun!), which of course aligns with the tag, [isolated-storage](/questions/tagged/isolated-storage).

When presented with choices like these, I usually favor the name or title that is used in writing over the code identifier, so I'd go with the hyphenated tag. Either way, when the tags are synonymized, only one tag will actually be shared by and displayed in questions, whichever is entered in the Tags field.

Also since Bill is asking that a few people weigh in, we'll hold off on doing anything for the moment.

Comment: I agree with this.  If you look at the casing of `IsolatedStorage`, it's intended to be two words, there's no reason to *not* hyphenate them in the tag.

Comment: Does the *concept* of "isolated storage" come up in other languages or frameworks?

Comment: @ChrisF: No I don't think so.